# Injecting CSS in a Moodle course format plugin

Tags: css, moodle

I am writing a so called 'format plugin' for Moodle. The output of this plugin needs to be styles using the CSS stored in the file styles.css, which is part of the plugin. Unfortunately changes are not updated on screen because of the rigor caching. By enabling the "Theme Design Mode" (Site Admin > Appearance > Theme Settings) this can be avoided, but Moodle will become incredibly slow - much to slow to work with it.

Other plugin types like 'activity plugins' allow custom definitions like 
`$PAGE->requires->css( '/path/to/my/custom.css');` followed by a command to write the HTML header `echo $OUTPUT->header();`. However, this does not work for format plugins. Moodle complains with the error: "Cannot require a CSS file after  has been printed.".

Loading the css during the runtime using AMD /Javascript calls, have no effect:

```
    var link;
    for(var i=0; i< css.length;i++){
      link = document.createElement("link");
      link.rel = "stylesheet";
      link.type = "text/css";
      link.href = css[i];
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
    }
```

Now, I am looking for an alternative way to inject a `<link href="/path/to/my/custom.css">` into the HTML  using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with `styles.css`, no need to enable Design Mode, but whenever you need to rebuild the css/theme cache run from the root of your Moodle project:

```
$ php admin/cli/purge_caches.php
```

After purging the Moodle cache Moodle will rebuild and serve the updated css (only the first request will be slow), but do not forget that you may also need to clear your browser cache.

Summarizing: update css, purge Moodle caches, browser "hard" refresh.

Comment: How shall I stick with the `styles.css` if I have several other css files that do not get referneces by using `@import url(...)` or `@import '...'`? Moodle replaces the file paths so that the files cannot be loaded.

Comment: you could treat them like if they were SCSS files and transpile them into one big style.css file. Pictures and fonts can be referenced using [[pix]] and [[font]] special placeholders, see: https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/How_to_add_custom_fonts_in_a_theme and https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_images_in_a_theme (the documentation talks about themes, but this works from other kinds of plugins too).